# (Py)Qt5: How to achieve global zooming over all objects of a widget

Tags: pyqt5, qt5

I have implemented a GUI displaying a bunch of data. On some screens, the content does not fit. So there is the idea to have something like a zoom as it is known from browsers where you can zoom in and out the content:
[image]

Is there a possibility to get something like this for QMainWindow or QWidget and recursively for all its sub-widgets?

Comment: No, widgets are not intended for that and are implemented to be shown at their preferred size, considering font size/scaling and eventually screen DPI and generally based on pixel sizes. While its possible to use a QGraphicsView with proxy widgets, it's not recommended for a full UI, as content can become blurry at certain scale ratios. You may reconsider the whole layout (assuming you *are* using [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), and you should, using scroll areas or split the UI in pages, tabs or windows.

Comment: By default, stylesheets are inherited from parents. You could use the slider to set the fontsize of the top-level widget and try to get the children to share the fontsize also. Idk about images, but you could see if this works for text

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If the content doesn't fit, you may need to redesign the GUI. Please therefore provide a [mre].